# Why does my console application freezes when using Win32_UserAccount class

Tags: c#, winapi, active-directory, user-accounts, wmi-query

When i add this code to my console application freezes.

```
List<string> User = new List<string>(); 

objectSearcher = new ManagementClass("Win32_UserAccount");
foreach (var item in objectSearcher.GetInstances())
{
    User.Add(item["FullName"].ToString());

}
```

I have no idea why, can anyone help  ?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Are you running it in Active Directory environment or as a local account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it freezes due to large amount of data, `objectSearcher.GetInstances()` grabs every account from AD controller over network. How long it takes depends on number of accounts, network configuration and controller performance.